# set text between image in listview android

Tags: android

hi ihave list of some items and each list have one image in left corner and text is appearing to its right i want to show text between between image in listview so how to do it my xml is...

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"/>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you want to set image as background for item?

Comment: like 1st image showing in screen shot url androidpeople.com/tag/gravity image then text but middle of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new view with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the preview it centers the text of the TextView between picture and boarder. So this should work. How do you add new elements to the list? Do you use a customized ArrayAdapter in your Controller to handle the add of elements?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to create a list with a Image on the left side and a text beside it? If this is the point you have to implement your own array adapter. Then you can set a image and text vor each row of the list.
Maybe this link will help you: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: like 1st image showing in screen shot url androidpeople.com/tag/gravity image then text but middle of image

Comment: You want the text placed over the image or do you want to center the text in the rest of the space between image and right border?The 1st item on the page shows a image with a text beside.

Comment: want to center the text in the rest of the space between image and right borde

Comment: Did you try: android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" or android:gravity="center_horizontal"?

Comment: android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" it makes text center of screen but i want center with respect of image in list view

Answer (score 0):

you can use soemtihng like these

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="16sp" 
    android:drawableLeft="R.drawble.img"
    android:drawableRight="R.drawble.img2"
/>
```

Comment: like 1st image showing in screen shot url  http://www.androidpeople.com/tag/gravity image then text but middle of image